# How to authenticate Jira Rest Client with SAML authentication?

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, jira, saml, jira-rest-api

How to modify following example, so that it works with SAML based authentication:

```
var jiraConn = Jira.CreateRestClient(
    "https://alm.mycompany.com/jira", 
    "username", 
    "password");
var projects = await jiraConn.Projects.GetProjectsAsync();
```

Comment: Assuming you are using TechTalk.JiraRestClient? Or some other client library? 
There is some documentation about SAML: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/saml-single-sign-on-873871238.html

Comment: I'm using Atlassian.SDK nuget

Answer (score 1):

You have to steal cookie and then:

```
string cookie = ....;
var jiraConn = Jira.CreateRestClient(url);
jiraConn.RestClient.RestSharpClient.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
jiraConn.RestClient.RestSharpClient.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri(url), cookie);
```

In order to steal cookie

1. Open you browser and navigate to your jira portal
2. Open developer tools and capture network traffic
3. Reload your issues for example (click on search button) in order to trigger request
4. See the request in developer tools and copy the cookie header value.